# como paso diversas variables

Tags: php, sql, while

Tengo esta función que calcula la distancia entre 2 puntos.
Con un punto funciona bien, pero quisiera hacerlo con varios a la vez, y no se como pasarle 1 a 1 los resultados de mi consulta SQL.

```
 <?php
    function distanceCalculation($point1_lat, $point1_long, $point2_lat, $point2_long, $unit = 'km', $decimals = 2)
    {
        // Cálculo de la distancia en grados
        $degrees = rad2deg(acos((sin(deg2rad($point1_lat))*sin(deg2rad($point2_lat))) + (cos(deg2rad($point1_lat))*cos(deg2rad($point2_lat))*cos(deg2rad($point1_long-$point2_long)))));

        switch($unit) 
        {
            case 'km':
                $distance = $degrees * 111.13384; // 1 grado = 111.13384 km, basándose en el diametro promedio de la Tierra (12.735 km)
                break;
        }
        return round($distance, $decimals);
            echo $distance;
    }
    include ("trae_datos.php");

    $point1 = array("lat" => "$puntos_de_control[0]", "long" => "$puntos_de_control[1]");//control
    $point2 = array("lat" => "-36.61090308325109", "long" => "-72.11079239845276"); //gps
    $km = distanceCalculation($point1['lat'], $point1['long'], $point2['lat'], $point2['long']);

    //echo "La distancia entre el punto 1 y el punto 2 es de $km km";

    if($km<0.05)
    {
        echo "se encuentra dentro del punto de control ".$puntos_de_control[2];
    }

    else 
    {
    echo "aun no llegas al punto de control '" .$puntos_de_control[2];
    }
```

Comment: Quizá de tu consulta de SQL obtén un arreglo de puntos, y vas llamando tu función cuantas veces lo ocupes por cada punto.

Comment: de esta manera traigo los datos $puntos_de_control = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);